# Using Dash's dcc.Loading component with a callback running a sql query

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'd like to use `dcc.Loading` with a callback that is running an sql query based on user input. I am thinking of a spinner pop-up when the query is running and processing the result.

https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/loading

Here's a simplified / minimal example for Illustration:

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
from dash import dcc, html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas 
import numpy 
import mapbox
from app import app

# Mapbox
MAPBOX_KEY="pk.xxxxxxx"
token = MAPBOX_KEY
Geocoder = mapbox.Geocoder(access_token=token)

# mysql connection
import pymysql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
user = 'user1'
pwd = 'xxxx'
host =  'xasdas'
port = 3306
database = 'main'
engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}".format(user,pwd,host,database))
con = engine.connect()

layout = html.Div([ 
                                   dcc.Input( id = "selection", type = "search", list = "list1" ) , 
 
                                   dcc.Graph(id="map1"),

                ])

app.callback([ 
                          Output("map". "figure")
                       ],
                       [
                          Input("selection","value")
                       ]
def update_map(selection):

      data = []
 
       if selection:
          
           query = '''
                          select x, y, z
                          from table1
                          where val = {}
                         '''.format(selection)

            df = pd.read_sql(query, con)

            data.append({

                        "type": "scattermapbox",
                        "lat": df['x'],
                        "lon": df['y'],
                        "name": "Location",
                        "hovertext": propname,
                        "mode": "markers",
                        "clickmode": "event+select",
                        "marker": {
                            "autocolorscale": False,
                            "showscale":True,
                            "symbol": "circle",
                            "size": 9,
                            "opacity": 0.8,
                            "color": df['z'],
                            }
                     }
            )

       layout = {

                 "autosize": True,
                 "hovermode": "closest",
                 "mapbox": {

                     "accesstoken": MAPBOX_KEY,
                     "bearing": 0,
                     "center": {
                         "lat": x,
                         "lon": y
                     },
                     "pitch": 0,
                     "zoom": zoom,
                     "style": "streets",

                 },

                 "margin": {
                    "r": 0,
                    "t": 0,
                    "l": 0,
                    "b": 0,
                    "pad": 0
                }

    } 

   return ({"data": data, "layout": layout})
```

This query could take a long time due to large volume of data, indices etc. to populate `data` `list` and update the `map layout`. For better UX, how do I use the `dcc.Loading` component while the query is running and processing the data?

Comment: Just wrap the component you'll be updating with the `dcc.Loading` component. It sounds like the real issue might be how long your query takes, though. If it causes problems, you may need to look at the new long-running callback pattern.